# Does spinach when cooked on bare cast iron turn black?

Tags: cast-iron, spinach, greens

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookware#Cast_iron):

> In addition, some foods (such as spinach) cooked on bare cast iron will turn black.

How true is that, and why? Secondly, does it even apply to the ***newly***-seasoned cast iron cookware?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spinach contains oxalic acid which reacts with cast iron and carbon steel pans turning the spinach black.

I'm not sure about your second question, I would suggest trying it and seeing what happens. My hunch would be that as long as you have a good seasoned coating on the pan it should be fine. But that's only supposition.